# Are expression-bodied methods automatically inlined?

Tags: c#, inline, expression-body

Are expression-bodied methods automatically inlined?

Are the following equivalent in non-debug compilation?

```
        public byte[] GetBytes(char value) => GetBytesInternal(value, 2);
```

```
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public byte[] GetBytes(char value) => GetBytesInternal(value, 2);
```

Is there any guide to when inlining is done by compiler, so as to avoid these messy attributes?

Comment: Why not create a program and see the IL output?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica - Inlining decisions are a JIT compiler decision, not the C# compiler (hence the existence of the attribute). In the IL, the method will not be inlined.